# What does it mean an object to be initiated once but called by different threads? ( I mean Servlets.. )

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

So I know that there is only one instance of a Servlet, and the methods of the Servlets are called by different threads.. I want to understand this concept but I am having a hard time..

Imagine I have this class with one method:

```
public class A{

    public void foo(Bar bar){
    }

}
```

How can there be a single object of A, but it will be called by different threads? Any help?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you need help with. There is one object, A. It exists somewhere in memory. Then lots of threads execute the `foo` function on object A. What's confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a program that illustrates the concept using your example:

```
// Here is your class
public class A {
    public void foo(Bar bar){
        System.out.println(bar);
    }
}
// Here is a class with a main that runs foo(Bar) on five threads
public class Demo extends Thread {
    static A sharedA = new A();
    Bar myBar = new Bar();
    public void run() {
        sharedA.foo(myBar);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
            (new Demo()).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Above, there is only one instance of `A`, because `sharedA` is `static`. `main()` creates five threads, with each thread calling a method `foo` on the shared instance of `A`.

You can play with this demo a little - for example, try changing `A` to count the calls of `foo`, and run it from a few hundred threads. You will discover that if you simply increment the counter, you get inconsistent results, and that you need to use synchronization or atomic integer to do the counting correctly.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. And this is how Servlets work basically, right?

Comment: @KorayTugay Well, not exactly - the threads that access Servlet are initiated by incoming requests. Also the Servlet object might not necessarily be stored in a static variable. But the sharing is the same: the Servlet object is created only once at application startup, and then all requests call the same methods from different threads.